# Top-down approach poorly implemented

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have been kinda practicing some recursive / dynamic programming exercises, but I have been struggling trying to convert this recursive problem into a top-down one, as for example, for f(4,4), the recursive one yields 5, whereas my top-down yields 2.

I can see the base cases being the same, so I might be messing up with the logic somehow, but I haven't found where.

the code is as written:

```
def funct(n, m):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if m == 0 or n < 0:
        return 0
    return funct(n-m, m) + funct(n, m-1)
```

and the top-down approach is:

```
def funct_top_down(n, m):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if m == 0 or n < 0:
        return 0
    memo = [[-1 for x in range(m+1)] for y in range(n+1)]
    return funct_top_down_imp(n, m, memo)

def funct_top_down_imp(n, m, memo):
    if memo[n][m] == -1:
        if n == 0:
            memo[n][m] = 1
        elif m == 0 or n < 0:
            memo[n][m] = 0
        else:
            memo[n][m] = funct_top_down_imp(n-m, m, memo) + funct_top_down_imp(n, m-1, memo)
    return memo[n][m]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need fix your `indentation` first.

Comment: @DanielHao yeah thanks, I've just fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to compute all possible values of `func` instead of just one. Sounds like a lot, but since `func` needs all previous values anyways, this would be actually the same amount of work.

We place computed values in a matrix `N+1 x M+1` for given `N, M` so that it holds that

```
 matrix[n][m] === func(n, m)
```

Observe that the first row of the matrix will be all `1`, since `f(0,m)` returns `1` for every `m`. Then, starting from the second row, compute the values left to right using your recursive dependency:

```
matrix[n][m] = matrix[n-m][m] + matrix[n][m-1]
```

(don't forget to check the bounds!)

Upon completion, your answer will be in the bottom right corner of the matrix. Good luck!

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the fast reply, I might have expressed my question wrong, but, I think I understood what you were pointing out, the problem is that, I get different values, even tho, from my point of view, they do the same in my functions.